# Recursively defining and visiting a `boost::variant` using an `std::vector` containing an incomplete type - libstdc++ vs libc++

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, libc++, boost-variant

I am trying to define and visit a "recursive" [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html) using an [*incomplete*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) wrapper class and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as my indirection techniques. My implementation works with **libstdc++**, but not with **libc++**.

---

This is the way I am defining my variant:

```
struct my_variant_wrapper;

using my_variant_array = std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>; // <- indirection here
using my_variant = boost::variant<int, my_variant_array>;

struct my_variant_wrapper
{
    my_variant _v;

    template <typename... Ts>
    my_variant_wrapper(Ts&&... xs) : _v(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...) { }
};
```

I am using `std::vector` to introduce indirection *(so that dynamic allocation will prevent `my_variant` to have infinite size)*.

I am quite confident I am allowed to use `std::vector<my_variant_wrapper>`, where `my_variant_wrapper` is an [*incomplete type*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type), because of [paper **N4510** *("Minimal incomplete type support for standard containers")*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html):

- The paper was approved, according to [WG21's 2015 page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/).
- The features has always been supported in **libstdc++**, according to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z).
- It was implemented in **libc++ 3.6**, according to [this page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).

---

I am then visiting the variant as follows:

```
struct my_visitor
{
    void operator()(int x) const { }
    void operator()(const my_variant_array& arr) const
    {
        for(const auto& x : arr)            
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, x._v);            
    }
};

int main()
{
    my_variant v0 = my_variant_array{
        my_variant{1}, my_variant{2}, my_variant_array{
            my_variant{3}, my_variant{4}
        }
    };

    boost::apply_visitor(my_visitor{}, v0);
}
```

[**A minimal complete example is available on coliru.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a44c80fcdfec6e80)

---

- I'm using the following flags:

  > -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
- `BOOST_VERSION` evaluates to `106100`.

The code:

- **Compiles and runs** as intended on:

  - g++ *(tested versions: 6.1 and 7)*, with **libstdc++**.
  - clang++ *(tested versions: 3.8)*, with **libstdc++**.
  - *(as a bonus, it also works with `std::variant` by making the appropriate changes!)*
- **Fails to compile** on:

  - clang++ *(tested versions: 3.8, 4)*, with **libc++**.

---

This is the error I get while compiling on clang++ with libc++:

```
In file included from prog.cc:2:
In file included from /usr/local/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/variant.hpp:17:
/usr/local/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1537:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'initialize'
              initializer::initialize(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1692:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, std::__1::vector<my_variant_wrapper, std::__1::allocator<my_variant_wrapper> > >::convert_construct<my_variant_wrapper>' requested here
        convert_construct(operand, 1L);
        ^
prog.cc:15:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, std::__1::vector<my_variant_wrapper, std::__1::allocator<my_variant_wrapper> > >::variant<my_variant_wrapper>' requested here
    my_variant_wrapper(Ts&&... xs) : _v(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...) { }
                                     ^
/usr/local/libcxx-head/include/c++/v1/memory:1783:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'my_variant_wrapper::my_variant_wrapper<my_variant_wrapper &>' requested here
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^
/usr/local/libcxx-head/include/c++/v1/memory:1694:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator<my_variant_wrapper>::construct<my_variant_wrapper, my_variant_wrapper &>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^

...
```

[**The full error is available on wandbox.**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ifzeGqfZvznCLDep)

---

**Why is the code not compiling with libc++?**  *(Could this be a defect in libc++'s N4510 implementation that needs to be reported?*)

The error seems to suggest that the variant fails to detect what members should be initialized, but I honestly couldn't make much sense of it. I am also confused by the fact that using **libstdc++** *(with the same boost version)* works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw this in the backtrace:

> note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   '`my_variant_wrapper::my_variant_wrapper<my_variant_wrapper &>`'
>   requested here

which is a clear indication that your constructor template is hijacking the copy constructor.

Constrain it, and your problem disappears.

---

The difference between implementations is due to the way `vector`'s copy constructor copies the elements. libstdc++ treats the source elements as `const`:

```
vector(const vector& __x)
  : _Base(__x.size(),
    _Alloc_traits::_S_select_on_copy(__x._M_get_Tp_allocator()))
{
    this->_M_impl._M_finish =
    std::__uninitialized_copy_a(__x.begin(), __x.end(),
                                this->_M_impl._M_start,
                                _M_get_Tp_allocator());
}
```

Because `begin()` and `end()` are called on `const vector& x`, they return constant iterators.

libc++ treats the source elements as non-`const`:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::vector(const vector& __x)
    : __base(__alloc_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(__x.__alloc()))
{
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
    __get_db()->__insert_c(this);
#endif
    size_type __n = __x.size();
    if (__n > 0)
    {
        allocate(__n);
        __construct_at_end(__x.__begin_, __x.__end_, __n);
    }
}
```

`__begin_` and `__end_` are `pointer`s, and since `const` is shallow, the `const`-ness of `__x` doesn't make the pointee `const`.

Both are conforming, since `CopyInsertable` requires copyability from both `const` and non-`const` sources. However, your template only hijacks copying from non-`const` (because it loses the copying from `const` case by the template/non-template tiebreaker), so you only see the problem in libc++.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! [It compiles with **libc++**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TCBfoFPrEZHFE8G0) when constrained. I'm still puzzled on why this error only occurs with libc++ though - could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Just spent some more time digging - see edit.

Comment: So libc++'s vector attempts to copy-construct the vector elements using a non-const lvalue reference, whereas libstdc++ passes a const lvalue reference. Because libc++ uses a non-const reference it chooses the template constructor instead of the copy constructor.